Using data within a SQL table to build a WHERE-Object condition
I have been using PS for about 8-9 years. I want to use a SQL table to store a list of values to use in an exclusion WHERE Object clause.  The source data is NOT in SQL.  It is coming from a data set coming from an Outlook COM object.  Basically I want to filter out emails that have certain keywords in the subject.  It already has a static list that works just fine, but I would like to give the users the ability to modify this list without updating the code.  Here is what I have.  It looks like it 'Should' work.  In fact, if I render the filter and past it into the WHERE Object, it does work.  Just not with the string variable.
$dsExclude = Select-SQL "SELECT Keyword = LTRIM(RTRIM(Keyword)) FROM Email_Mining_Keywords WHERE Action='Exclude' AND WordLocation='Subject'" -ConnectionStringOrSetting $DestConnectionString  


$filter = ($dsExclude | select -ExpandProperty KeyWord | % { "`$_.Subject -NOTlike '*$_*'" }) -join ' -and '
$dsResults |   ?{$filter} | Out-GridView

It took me awhile to figure out that I needed to escape the pipe character from the source dataset while parsing the pipe character from the exclusion dataset.  When rendering the filter variable, it looks great & works when manually pasting the filter.

what you're looking for is $filter = [scriptblock]::Create($filter) then ? $filter (no {..}). However what you're trying to do is terribly inefficient. You could just build a single regex OR pattern and do ? { $_.Subject -notmatch $bigOrRegexPattern }

Pretty sure this was mentioned by someone in the exact same text posted as a different question previously, but your $filter is a non-empty [string], not an executable expression, so your where-object (the ? { ... }) is equivalent to where-object { $true }.

Wow, thanks Santiago & mclayton.  The [scriptblock]::Create( was what I was missing. Perfect.  Thank you.

The issue with your current approach is that you're evaluating a string in the -FilterScript scriptblock and, unless empty, a string is always true.
'foo' | Where-Object { 'any non empty string is true' }

What you wanted to do instead is to create an expression that is used to filter the collection:
$filter = [scriptblock]::Create(
    $dsExclude.ForEach{ "`$_.Subject -notlike '*$($_.KeyWord)*'" } -join ' -and ')

$dsResults | Where-Object $filter | Out-GridView

This approach is however inefficient and hard to understand, there is a much easier way to approach this problem by creating a regex OR pattern:
# here it is required to escape the value of `KeyWord` to match literally.
# this prevents false positives in case the value could contain special regex characters
$filter = $dsExclude.ForEach{ [regex]::Escape($_.KeyWord) } -join '|'
$dsResults | Where-Object { $_.Subject -notmatch $filter } | Out-GridView


Thanks Santiago.  I will keep the regex in mind.  The data sets are very small<50 rows.with the regex, it removes the need for wildcards, yes? so if the keyword is in the subject it matches and will be excluded, correct?

thats correct @KevinAlbrecht, there is no need for wildcards (*) if using the regex approach. much simpler.

Great.  Thanks for this approach.  I have tested it & it is in UAT.
